# Wireframes Stencil: should I use Visio or Visual Studio?

Tags: wireframe

We need a simple method to put together wireframes. What is the simplest way to achieve this? Visio? Looks like we need to buy a stencil.

I also read somewhere online (on msdn) without no links provided that you can do it in Visual Studio.

I need the ability to portray the following controls:

- links
- text fields
- buttons
- datagrids
- tree

Comment: This is a request for library/off-site recommendations, and can thus be put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at ForeUI, it is quite interesting: http://www.foreui.com/

Comment: ForeUI is definitely worth trying.

Answer (score 4):

Balsamiq Mockups, look no further.  http://www.balsamiq.com/

Comment: I second this recommendation, Balsamiq Mockups is great and improving everytime.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need:

- High-fidelity vs low-fidelity
- Do you need to create mockups in realtime (with your users)
- Do you need "sketchy" look
- Who will use it (only programmers or civilians too)
- Mockups of what: web, desktop, mobile
- Only handful of "main" screens/pages vs dozens of scenarios with hundreds of screens
- etc etc

Here is the pretty comprehensive list of many mockup tools, both free and commercial:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

Back in 2005 I've created my own tool ([MockupScreens](http://mockupscreens.com), it's on the above list and it's pretty popular) specifically for non-programmers to be able to prototype realtime in a meeting, and to quickly get something close to a spec.

Bottom-line is that for different uses, some tools are more appropriate than others...

Answer (score 0):

Both those applications are great! Their drawback is that you cannot create a whole specification document. Axure will solve that problem for you although it lacks alot of the widgets Balsamiq and Foreui have.

I am not aware of Visual Studio having any wireframing facilities. It can generate class diagrams though.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [softandGUI - UXToolbox](http://www.softandgui.co.uk), it supports all different types of apps and devices and is it's great for creating high quality, pixel-perfect wireframes that can be linked together to form simple working prototypes that look and work just like the finished app. Also allows you to annotate and document your screens and export the finished thing to PNGs or Word.